# String and Date Comparison failing after the first call

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a function that will decide what to do based on whether all passed in values are the same or not.

```vb
If ((strBillingRate = strOrgBill) And 
   (strFreq = strOrigFreq)) And 
   ((Convert.ToDateTime(strStartDate).ToShortDateString = Convert.ToDateTime(strOrigStartDate).ToShortDateString) And 
   (Convert.ToDateTime(strEndDate).ToShortDateString = Convert.ToDateTime(strOrigEndDate).ToShortDateString)) Then
    ' do something 
Else
    ' do something else
End If
```

I've noticed that even though the values being passed in do not change at all the function will work correctly the first time it is called, but anytime after that even though the parameters do not change whatsoever the function proceeds to the do something else portion.
Am I comparing these strings and dates wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [repro].

Comment: Can you prove it with an MCVE please? You essentially seem to be saying "I have a function F that tests if two arguments are equal and the first time I call `F(1,1)` it says true, and the next time i call `F(1,1)` it says false" - i kinda need to see the surrounding context to that before i can believe it. Something must have changed

Comment: Please also look at `And` vs `AndAlso` and also consider that this code you have here is really fragile..

Comment: Why do you need to convert the date variables from a string to a date time, then back to string for the comparison?  Why not just strStartDate = strOrigStartDate and so on?

Comment: It's impossible that the same code will do two different things under the same set of circumstances. Something must be different and you have to find out exactly what. Have you even debugged the code?

Comment: Why are you making your code harder to read by adding all those pointless parentheses? You have six sets of parentheses that do absolutely nothing. You should get rid of them.

Comment: One has to wonder why you have dates as `Strings` in the first place but, if you're going to convert them to `Dates`, you should then compare them as `Dates`. Don't convert them back to `Strings` again.